Notifications "action" button position
I try to create a vue/bootstrap notifications component with action buttons.
Thats my current result, no matter what i do, the buttons are part of the notification body itself:

Instead of that, i want the buttons at the bottom:

The button(s) should take up the whole width.
Current version of the vue component:
<template>
  <ul class="toast-container position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 1050;">
    <li v-for="(notification, index) in notifications" :key="index"
      class="toast show align-items-center text-white border-0 mb-2 auto-dissmis" @click="removeNotification(index)">
      <div class="toast-indicator" :class="'bg-' + notification.type"></div>
      <div class="toast-body" v-html="notification.message"></div>
      <div class="toast-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary d-block" @click="action.handler(action, $event)"
          v-for="action in notification.actions">
          {{ action.title }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Notification",
  data() {
    return {
      notifications: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNotification(message, opts) {

      opts = Object.assign({
        message,
        type: "primary",
        actions: [{
          title: "Foo",
          handler: (self, event) => {

            if (event) {
              event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();
            }

            alert("Clicked", self, event);

          }
        }]
      }, opts);

      this.notifications.push(opts);

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.notifications.length > 0) {
          //this.notifications.shift();
        }
      }, 2400);

    },
    removeNotification(index) {
      this.notifications.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
  mounted() {

    this.addNotification(`Sample notification #1`);

    /*
    ["info", "primary", "success", "warning", "danger"].forEach((color, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addNotification(`Sample notification #${i}`, color);
      }, i * 1000);
    });
    */

  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn-group button:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group button:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.toast-container {
  width: 380px;
  list-style: none;
}

.toast {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #343a40 !important
}

.toast-footer {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}


.toast-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;

}

.toast-actions {
  margin: 0;
}

li.auto-dissmis>.toast-indicator {
  animation: progress 2.4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
</style>

</style>


Found a solution.
Create two div's inside the li element, one for the toast itself, one for the buttons:
<template>

  <!--
  <ul class="toast-container position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 1050;">

    <li class="toast show align-items-center text-white border-0 mb-2 auto-dissmis">
      <div class="toast-indicator"></div>
      <div class="toast-body">
        Hello Wrodl Message

      </div>
      <div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary flex-fill">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary flex-fill">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary flex-fill">Right</button>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
  -->


  <ul class="toast-container position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 1050;">

    <li v-for="(notification, index) in notifications" :key="index" @click="removeNotification(index)" class="mb-2 ">
      <div class="toast align-items-center text-white border-0"
        :class="{ 'toast-no-bottom-border-radius': notification.actions.length > 0 }">
        <div class="toast-indicator" :class="'bg-' + notification.type"></div>
        <div class="toast-body" v-html="notification.message"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group d-flex">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary flex-fill" v-for="(action, index) in notification.actions"
          :key="index" @click="action.handler(action, $event)">
          {{ action.title }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Notification",
  data() {
    return {
      notifications: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNotification(message, opts) {

      opts = Object.assign({
        message,
        type: "primary",
        actions: []
      }, opts);

      this.notifications.push(opts);

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.notifications.length > 0) {
          //this.notifications.shift();
        }
      }, 2400);

    },
    removeNotification(index) {
      this.notifications.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
  mounted() {

    let handler = (self, event) => {

      if (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      alert("Clicked", self, event);

    };

    this.addNotification(`Sample notification #1`, {
      actions: [{
        title: "Foo",
        handler,
      }, {
        title: "Bar",
        handler,
      }]
    });

    this.addNotification(`Sample notification #2`, {
      type: "success"
    });

    /*
    ["info", "primary", "success", "warning", "danger"].forEach((color, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.addNotification(`Sample notification #${i}`, color);
      }, i * 1000);
    });
    */

  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn-group button:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group button:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.toast-container {
  width: 380px;
  list-style: none;
}

.toast {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #343a40 !important
}

.toast-no-bottom-border-radius {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.toast-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
}

.toast-actions {
  margin: 0;
}

.btn-group button {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

li.auto-dissmis>div.toast>.toast-indicator {
  animation: progress 2.4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
</style>


